# Why union type not accepting one of its types in Julia?

Tags: julia

Why union type `Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}` is not accepting `Array{Float64,1}`

```
function somefn(; serie::Vector{Union{Missing, Float64}})
end
serie = [1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 4.0]
somefn(serie = serie)


ERROR: TypeError: in keyword argument serie, expected Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}, got Array{Float64,1}
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::var"#kw##somefn")(::NamedTuple{(:serie,),Tuple{Array{Float64,1}}}, ::typeof(somefn)) at ./none:0
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[12]:1
```

One way to fix it is to remove `Vector{Union{Missing, Float64}}` from function signature, I don't want to do that, I want to explicitly limit possible types for function arguments to reduce the bugs and easier understand how function works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is explained in The Julia Manual in the section on [Parametric Composite Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#Parametric-Composite-Types-1).

In short in Julia types, except tuples are invariant. Citing the documentation:

> This last point is very important: even though `Float64 <: Real` we DO NOT have `Point{Float64} <: Point{Real}`.

The way to fix your code to work is to write either:

```
function somefn(; serie::Vector{<:Union{Missing, Float64}})
end
```

or

```
function somefn(; serie::Vector{T}) where {T<:Union{Missing, Float64}}
end
```

which is explained later in that section of the manual.

The key thing to understand is that `Vector{<:Union{Missing, Float64}}` matches all types whose parameter is a subtype of `Union{Missing, Float64}`, whereas in `Vector{Union{Missing, Float64}}` the parameter must match `Union{Missing, Float64}` exactly.

Therefore in your original code example the following call:

```
somefn(serie = Union{Float64,Missing}[1,2,3])
```

would work as type parameter would match.